# Webpack - build bundle without dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I;m wondering if it's possible to build a bundle with some javascript files but without dependencies?

I want to have small bundles with React components (each react component in my case is builded from few react components, for example Comment component incldues comment box, list, and form),
I can split React components to a separate files by specifying few entry points in webpack, but if I have:
1. Component comment
2. Component newsletter
and both of them require ReactDOM, files which will be generated will have like 600kb, where my react components contain only ~100 lines of js code.

I would like to have one more file which will contain all the code which would come from "require('react-dom'), and those two files which will only have the React component code. is that possible?

My current setup:

```
'use strict';
import path from 'path';
import CommonsChunkPlugin from "webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin";
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./app.js",
        newsletter: "./components/renderers/newsletter.renderer.js",
        comment: "./components/renderers/comment.renderer.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname),
        filename: "built/[name].entry.js"
    },
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: [/(node_modules)/],
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "comment.js",
            chunks: ["comment", "app"],
            minChunks: 2
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "newsletter.js",
            chunks: ["newsletter", "app"],
            minChunks: 2
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment.renderer.js:

```
import CommentBox from './../comment/commentBox';
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox/>,
    document.getElementById("comment")
);
```

Newsletter.renderer.js:

```
import Newsletter from './../newsletter/newsletter';
ReactDOM.render(
    <Newsletter/>,
    document.getElementById("newsletter")
);
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import client from './lib/client';
```

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#commonschunkplugin

Comment: Webpack should automatically be de-duplicating code. Can you elaborate more on your setup?

Comment: I've updated my post. I will just add that I have removed all imports from CommentBox and Newsletter. Maybe I should import app.js ? I would assume that with such config on my page I need to include:

Comment: comment.js, newsletter.js and app.js, but comment.js have 666kb, newletter got 4kb and app.js have 1kb. If I will want to include newsletter on different page it won't work, because i want to include only app.js and newsletter.js right?

Comment: Small update. In one of the comment components files there was an import of react, that's why it had 666kb. After removing that everything has 6kb, which is also invalid because there is not react or react-dom code. How to create such "commons.js" file?

Comment: And I have updated config file once again, now with this config file i got: big app.entry.js file, small react components files and after deploy I get error: Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I've managed how to do that:

```
import path from 'path';
import CommonsChunkPlugin from "webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin";
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ["react","react-dom", "underscore"],
        comment: "./components/renderers/comment.renderer.js",
        newsletter: "./components/renderers/newsletter.renderer.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname),
        filename: "built/[name].bundle.js"
    },
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: [/(node_modules)/],
                loader: 'babel'
            }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "vendor",
            minChunks: Infinity
        })
    ]
};
```

this part:

```
minChunks: Infinity
```

will ensure that code included in bundle "vendor" is not included in any other bundle. Thanks to this approach, comment and newsletter will contain only my React components.

Comment: As of 2021 [Common Chunks Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) has been removed

Answer (score 6):

I use following code in webpack.config.js to exclude the external dependencies from bundle.

```
module.exports = {
     ...
     ...
    externals:{
       "react": "React",
       "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
     },
     ...
     ...
}
```

I found this answer from [this link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275#issuecomment-176255624)

Answer (score 4):

To complement @AnandShanbhag's answer, you can take all the dependencies from `package.json` and turn them into externals with a function:

```js
module.exports = {

    ...

    // put everything inside package.json dependencies as externals
    externals: Object.keys(require('./package.json').dependencies)
        .reduce(
            function (acc, cur) {
                acc[cur] = cur
                return acc
            },
            new Object()
        ),

    ...

}
```