# Using Webpack to include React from CDN, but not ReactDOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-dom

In my webpack build, I would like to load React from a CDN, but *not* ReactDOM, as it requires an extra roundtrip for a very small file.

My webpack configuration has the following block of code declaring "externals" so that it will *not* build these files (I instead include CDNs).

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

externals: {
    react: 'React'
},

...
```

The problem is that *only* including React in externals still builds React because ReactDOM depends on it.

**node_modules/react-dom/index.js**

```
module.exports = require('react/lib/ReactDOM');
```

Adding `'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'` to externals effectively removes them both from the bundle, but I don't want to have to include the ReactDOM CDN...

*How can I configure webpack to load React from a CDN, but include ReactDOM in my main bundle?*

---

Note: I'm using webpack 2.1.0-beta17 and React 15.1.0.

---

**Update**
I tried adding `react/lib/ReactDOM` to externals.

```
...

externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react/lib/ReactDOM': 'commonjs react-dom'
},

...
```

But I get the following error.

> require is not defined

Comment: But it says it's [intended to be included with React](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-dom), so when you put React on CDN you also have ReactDOM included.

Comment: Right, I just want to include ReactDOM in my bundle, rather than include CDN for it.

Comment: I don't understand the use case but I guess define `react-dom` as it's own Webpack entry and make it a [separate chunk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multiple-commons-chunks)?

Comment: Including `react-dom` as a separate chunk would not satisfy my intention to include it as part of my main bundle.

Comment: My best guess: try adding a webpack external for react/lib/ReactDOM.  Otherwise, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602831/webpack-build-bundle-without-dependencies?rq=1 for ideas.  Yet another idea: try the dedupe plugin.

Comment: Tried dedupe plugin with no luck, see above with regard to adding `react/lib/ReactDOM` to externals. I'll give the link you posted a look, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Not an answer, too big for comment]

See issues https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5413, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6128, which argue for having a CDN bundle of React+ReactDom, which would float your boat, if I understand correctly.  Dan Abramov feels it, so I'm hopeful.  Note, however, [his comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6128#issuecomment-189439034) that ReactDOM will get a lot bigger soon.

Comment: Very interesting stuff. Surprising to find that such bundle doesn't already exist.