# With WebPack, how do I create ready to use "split" bundles with one depending on the other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browser

My question is very close to [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602831/webpack-build-bundle-without-dependencies) which' answers I *believe* still require another WebPack-step which I want to avoid. But here is the story first:

I have a Node module (let's call it `libfoo`) which provides some functionality and requires some third party modules,
and a *small* script `main.js` which provides the main entry point and requires `libfoo`:

**main.js:**

```
const foo = require('foo');
function main() {
    foo.bar();
}
main();
```

I now want to turn `libfoo` and `main.js` into **browser executable** deliverables using WebPack. And I want `libfoo` (which is quite large) to reside statically on the target systems while `main.js` is very small and changes quickly (just imagine a test scenario where `libfoo` is a module I want to test and `main.js` contains changing code snippets)

I managed to create two packages - let's call them `foo.browser.js` and `main.browser.js` - which *contain* all the needed functionality, but I can't manage to make `main.browser.js` correctly import `foo.browser.js`.

I'm not very into WebPack yet - and up to now I couldn't figure out what's happening. My current approach looks like this: I build `foo.browser.js` by running the following command:

```
webpack --output-filename foo.browser.js foo.js
```

And I have a `webpack.config.js` for `main.js` which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {'foo': 'foo'},  // don't know what I'm doing here - added `commonjs` and `root` randomly
}
```

I turn `main.js` into `main.browser.js` with a very similar command: `webpack --output-filename main.browser.js main.js`

Now I try to use those both files in file called `foo.html` containing these lines:

```
<script src="dist/foo.browser.js"></script>
<script src="dist/main.browser.js"></script>
```

But when I now open `foo.html` in a browser I get

```
external "foo":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at Object.foo (external "foo":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)  
    at Object../main.js (main.js:3)  
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

I fiddled around a little but (only randomly I'm afraid) but with no luck.

There is one constraint in my scenario which might be a difference to the other (working) examples I found: I need `foo.browser.js` and `main.browser.js` to be *"final"* i.E. they must run on the target system **without any further postprocessing** (like running WebPack again to turn them into a single bundle).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this type of configuration:

```
module.exports = [{
  resolve: {
    modules: ["."],
  },
  entry: {
    "foo": "foo.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    filename: "[name].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map",
    library: "foo",
    // libraryTarget: "umd",
  }
},{
  resolve: {
    modules: ["."],
  },
  entry: {
    "main": "main.js",
  },
  externals: {
    "foo": "foo",
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    filename: "[name].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[name].js.map",
  }
}];
```

This will produce two bundles in the `build/` subdirectory. The key to get `main` to use `foo` is:

1. The `"foo": "foo"` entry in `externals` for creating the `main` bundle. Whenever `main` requests `foo` it looks for it *externally* in a "module" named `foo`. I've put "module" into quotes because when you have bundles in the UMD format and you load them with `script`, there's no module system. Instead of looking for an actual module, the code will look for a global variable named `foo`.
2. The `foo` bundle exports itself into the global space as the variable `foo`, which allows it to be used by `main`.