# Exchangeable JS code together with modules generated from C++ possible in browsers?

Tags: javascript, c++, webpack, module, emscripten

As of today is there any way to combine native JS scripts with modules generated from C++ code (from Emscripten, chirp, clang-8+, ..) in a way that makes it possible to exchange/modify the script while *reusing* the modules (i.e. not having to re-process them) which works in both Node.js *and* browser environments?

This was a long sentence - let me give an example:

I want to write some (say test-) code in JavaScript which uses a library (say `foo`) implemented in C++.

My current (working) setup looks like this:

**Browser**

```
                          test1.js \
                                    \
                                     ===(webpack)==> full.js
                                    /
foo.cpp  ==(emscripten)==>  foo.js /
```

**Node.js:**

```
foo.cpp ==(gcc/N-API)==> foo.node <--(require)-- test1.js
```

The problem with the browser approach is that (AFAIK) I have to re-run WebPack every time I modify/exchange `test1.js` in order to bring the changes to the browser.

In my case running `webpack` can take a long time and the resulting artifacts are quite large (multiples of 10MB). Also I want to run the code on relatively small devices which don't have WebPack so I even have to transfer those artifacts to the devices every time.

So I'd now like to keep a pre-processed artifact containing my `foo` module (whatever this might look like) at one place (e.g. on the device) while exchanging only the relatively small native JavaScript code (`test1.js`). (Imagine a test scenario with hundreds of `test*.js` files executed in a row)

With modern browsers / tools, ES6, ESM or any approach you can think of - is there a way to accomplish this for browsers?

Bonus points go to an answer which allows me to write code which I can use in Node.js *and* browsers without modification.. :)

My apologies: this is a modification of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328524/with-webpack-how-do-i-create-ready-to-use-split-bundles-with-one-depending-on) question when I wanted to even go without WebPack but now I've lowered my expectations..

Comment: Do you actually need preprocessing or bundling?  If couldn't you stick `test1.js` and `foo.js` in seperate `<script>` tags?

Comment: Note: I don't know what emscripten was like when this question was posted, but it can now generate wasm and a js wrapper around the wasm which can be loaded in node or in a browser.